# Write and read different types to memory in C

Tags: c, pointers

**-Theory:**

I have a set of variables S with different types and I have a pointer P pointing to memory address with the size of S. Now, I want to assign all the values of S to P and then read them back.

The point behind this is to manually build something similar to structs.

**-What I did:**

Lets say that we have int i, char c, and char *s as our S

```
uint8_t* foo(int i, char c, char* s) {
    uint8_t* r = malloc(sizeof(i) + sizeof(c) + sizeof(s));
    *r = i;
    *(r+sizeof(i)) = c;
    *(r+sizeof(i)+sizeof(c)) = s;
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    uint8_t * a = foo(500, 'a', "hello");
    printf("%d, %c, %s\n", *a, *(a+sizeof(int)), (a+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)) );
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that I'm assigning my data to only the first byte and then reading only the first byte.

**-The Question:**

How can I tell the compiler that in foo on *r = i; assign i to the next 4 bytes of *r and then on the main read *a as 4 bytes and then do the same for c and s?

Comment: I hope you realise that `sizeof(s)` tells the function nothing about the string data passed to the function. It is the size of the pointer.

Comment: yes I do, I don't mind storing any type including pointers

Comment: In `*(r+sizeof(i)+sizeof(c)) = s;` that will neither copy the string, nor have room for the string pointer in `uint8_t`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm trying to copy the reference in there but the problem here is that it's converting it to an integer and then cut it to fit one byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast your lvalues, so that they have the right type:

```
uint8_t *foo(int i, char c, char *s) {
    uint8_t *r = malloc(sizeof i + sizeof c + sizeof s);
    *(int *)r = i;
    *(char *)(r + sizeof i) = c;
    *(char **)(r + sizeof i + sizeof c) = s;
    return r;
}
```

In order to read them, it is also necessary to cast to the appropriate type:

```
int main(void) {
    uint8_t *a = foo(500, 'a', "hello");
    printf("%d, %c, %s\n", *(int *)a, *(char *)(a + sizeof(int)), *(char **)(a + sizeof(int) + sizeof(char)));
    return 0;
}
```

As @chux pointed out in comments, this is indeed undefined behavior. In the same spirit as previously, it is possible to use C11 `_Alignof` operator to get standard-compliant code:

```
// Get the smallest multiple of _Alignof(type) >= off
#define GET_ALIGNED_OFFSET(off, type) ((off + _Alignof(type) - 1) / _Alignof(type) * _Alignof(type))

uint8_t *foo(int i, char c, char *s) {
    size_t offset1 = GET_ALIGNED_OFFSET(sizeof i, char);
    size_t offset2 = GET_ALIGNED_OFFSET(offset1 + sizeof c, char *);
    uint8_t *r = malloc(offset2 + sizeof s);
    *(int *)r = i;
    *(char *)(r + offset1) = c;
    *(char **)(r + offset2) = s;
    return r;
}
```

Though of course @David Cullen's answer remains the best solution from an engineering point of view.

Comment: `*(char **)(r + sizeof i + sizeof c) = s;`  may fail due to aliment requirements.

Comment: @chux: BTW I think the second statement `*(char *)(r + sizeof i)` is also undefined behavior, because the standard doesn't say that the alignment requirement of `char` is 1 (it's just the "weakest").

Comment: Certain it is implied.  A `char *` must tolerate a value with an odd value - one that references the very next address.  Even if `foo[100]` is always on some power-of-2 multiple boundary, `&foo[1]` is on some odd boundary  and `char *p = &foo[1]; bar(*p);`  is good code.

Answer (score 2):

I like to get the computer do the math whenever possible. In this situation, I would use a `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct multi_type {
    int i;
    char c;
    char *s;
};

struct multi_type *foo(int i, char c, char *s) {
    struct multi_type *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    result->i = i;
    result->c = c;
    result->s = s;
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    struct multi_type *a = foo(500, 'a', "hello");
    if (a) {
        printf("%d, %c, %s\n", a->i, a->c, a->s);
        free(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
500, a, hello
```

This code is also easier to maintain. If one of the types in the `struct multi_type` changes or I need to add a type, there is less code to change.

Comment: Actually, the point behind my question is to do something similar to what structs do but with higher freedom and by doing the math myself

Comment: It is not clear from the title or body of your question that you want to do the math yourself. You should consider updating the title and body of your question to be more clear. However, my answer will be useful for people who do not want to do the math manually.

Comment: This answer is portable and correct, unlike the undefined behavior of `*(char **)(r + sizeof i + sizeof c) = s;`.

Comment: @chux can you please explain why *(char **)(r + sizeof i + sizeof c) = s; has an undefined behavior?

Comment: @DavidCullen Off course it is! I will update the post

Comment: @Naheel As [commented here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334775/write-and-read-different-types-to-memory-in-c/41334984?noredirect=1#comment69873877_41334871), A pointer to a `char *` have have an alignment requirement.  "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undeﬁned" C11 §6.3.2.3.  My question for you  is why thought it was OK, what reference or instructor suggested that?

Comment: @chux No one suggested that, I'm trying to learn C on my own. I guess you made me think about it again and at this point I'm afraid that I need to stick to structs.